# Set a ModelState to an ActionResult in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a `View`, I've created a `<form>` that posts some data to another `Controller`, which is different from that one that redirected me to the View. In this second controller, i perform some data validations and then, if errors are found, I need to redirect the user again to the source View but with the edited ModelState (so that i can show the validation errors).

Any tips?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [PRG pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#prg) like Darin said.

Cheers!

Comment: This should have explanation rather than simple link since not it is expired

Answer (score 3):

Instead of redirecting back to the original controller can't you just `return View("~/Views/FirstController/Index.aspx")`? Another option would be to store the model inside `TempData` before redirecting and fetching it back from `TempData` in the first controller if available.